# Swift return function executed after the next line

Tags: arrays, json, swift, function, return

My code that is my call to my function is executed before.
My function is to just return the content of the page that I touch.

here is my function

```
func Post(data: String, url: String) -> Array<Dictionary<String, String>>{
var resultArray = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://genysix.alwaysdata.net/"+url+".php")!)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if let _ = error {
    }
    if let response = response {
        //Tester si la réponse est bonne par rapport au code d'erreur http
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        if (httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode < 300){
            do{ //Si la réponse est du JSON
                let resultJSON = try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                resultArray = resultJSON as! Array<Dictionary<String, String>>
                print(resultArray)

            }catch _{
            }
            //Si le code de la réponse n'est pas entre 200 et 300 alors il y a une erreur
        }else{
        }//fin test erreur HTTP
    }//fin test reponse
})
task.resume()
return resultArray
}
```

how I call:

```
var COUCOU = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let id = "5"
    let strID = "\"id\":\"\(id)\""
    let data = "parameters=[{"+strID+"}]"
    let url = "TicketsUserShow"
    COUCOU = Post(data, url: url)
    print(COUCOU)
    /*for table in resultArray{
        for(key,contenu) in table{
            print("\(key): \(contenu)")
        }
    }*/
}
```

and my result is :
for COUCOU: []

for resultArray:

```
[["ID": "2", "Titre": "La panne de Victor", "Urgence": "Tres haute", "Etat": "Rejete"], ["ID": "3", "Titre": "La panne acceptée d\'un petit homme", "Urgence": "Tres haute", "Etat": "En attente"]]
```

Anybody got a solution ?

Comment: `dataTaskWithRequest` is executed *asynchronously* ...

Comment: there is no answer my question